# Python: Extract lines between certain lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.6.7 64bit on Windows 7 64bit

*mydata.txt* (the actual file is very large, so readlines() is not an option)

The names after *#* are container names and they contain the objects starting with *'-'*

```
#abc contains:
date 20-Oct
- mmm
- nnn
- ooo
#def contains:
date 23-Oct
- ppp
#ghi contains:
date 24-Oct
- sss
- ttt
#jkl contains:
date 26-Oct
- uuu
- vvv
- www
```

Goal is to print only the following lines (i.e. contents of the container)

```
mmm, nnn, ooo @abc
ppp @def
sss, ttt @ghi
uuu, vvv, www @jkl
```

My code

```
import re

with open('mydata.txt', 'r') as infile:
    container = ''
    allcontents = ''
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith('contains:'):
            print(allcontents[:-2] + container)
            container = re.search('#(.+)\scontains', line).group(1)
            container = '@' + container
            allcontents = '' #reset allcontents

        if line.startswith('- '):
            content = re.search('-\s(.+)$', line).group(1)
            allcontents = allcontents + content + ', '
```

This produces the output

```
mmm, nnn, ooo@abc
ppp@def
sss, ttt@ghi
```

As you can see the last container "jkl" is not being printed. The output for it is there, but before it could print the loop ends.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you provide us with a rough estimate of the size of your text file "mydata.txt" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Austin said you need to print outside the loop. Here is the modification that give the output you desired:

```
import re

with open('mydata.txt', 'r') as infile:
    container = ''
    allcontents = ''
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith('contains:'):
            print(allcontents[:-2] + container)
            container = re.search('#(.+)\scontains', line).group(1)
            container = '@' + container
            allcontents = ''  # reset allcontents

        if line.startswith('- '):
            content = re.search('-\s(.+)$', line).group(1)
            allcontents = allcontents + content + ', '
    if container:
        print(allcontents[:-2] + container)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
print(allcontents[:-2] + container)
```

at the end outside loop.

You have your last lines already stored in `allcontents`, just that you didn't print it.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that :(